# Adding new key to registry doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I wrote two functions `install()` and `del()`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void install (char * fileAndPath, char * registryName)
{
    const unsigned long size = strlen(fileAndPath);
    HKEY software;
    HKEY mykey;
    long yRes = RegCreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion", &software);
long nResult = RegCreateKey(software, "Run", &mykey);
long j = RegSetValueEx(mykey, registryName, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)fileAndPath, size + 1);
if (yRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "Error: Could not create registry key yRes  " << "\tERROR: " << yRes << endl;
    else
        cout << "Success: Key created" << endl;
if (nResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "Error: Could not create registry key nResult " << "\tERROR: " << nResult << endl;
    else
        cout << "Success: Key created" << endl;
if (j != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "Error: Could not create registry key j" << "\tERROR: " << j << endl;
    else
        cout << "Success: Key created" << endl;
    RegCloseKey(mykey);
    RegCloseKey(software);
}

void del(char * registryName)
{
HKEY software;
HKEY mykey;
RegCreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion",&software);
RegCreateKey(software,"Run",&mykey);
RegDeleteValue(mykey, registryName);
RegCloseKey(mykey);
RegCloseKey(software);
}

int main() {
    install("C:\\Users\\Dannael\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\test.exe", "TestKey");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Program crashes after running, i can't find the problem.

EDIT: I've changed buffer size value as Roman R. said, but program still doesn't want to add key to registry..

EDIT2: I've updated code.

Output:

```
    Success: Key created
    Error: Could not create registry key nResult ERROR: 5
    Error: Could not create registry key j ERROR: 6
```

Partly solved:

Changing values HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKEY_CURRENT_USER allow to write keys in registry for current user

Comment: Try checking whether the functions you call are succeeding, and if not printing the error code returned.

Comment: Your code reports only the last error, which is error 6 (invalid handle) which is a cascade failure because one of the earlier steps failed. You need to check for errors after every step.

Comment: Wrong `j` here: `... registry key nResult" << "\tERROR: " << j ...`

Comment: Yes error 5 is access denied, and writing to the per-user registry will overcome that.

Answer (score 2):

```
char buffer[60];
strcpy(buffer, fileAndPath);
```

You are unsafely copying 87 character long string into smaller 60 character long buffer. Hence buffer overflow.

Once you are done with this (larger buffer to hold the string, and [`strcpy_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) variant of the copying function), you are to find out how to:

- step through you code under debugger
- check result/status codes you get from API calls

Result checking:

```
LONG nResult = RegCreateKey(software, "Run", &mykey);
// If nResult is not ERROR_SUCCESS then hurry up to post this additional 
// information on StackOverflow: 
//   the line exactly, and the value of the nResult variable
```

Comment: Remove trailing ` \ ` from `... CurrentVersion\\ ` now?

Comment: i can't remove them.. i get error and warnings then
i.e 
>>  error: incomplete universal character name \U
>>  warning: unknown escape sequence: '\D' [enabled by default]

etc

Comment: You can. Both trailing backslashes, they don't make sense there.

Comment: If i did correctly what you said..  it still not working.. i changed values to  RegCreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\\",&software);

Comment: "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion"

Comment: You should really start checking returned codes to see where your error is.

Comment: @paradine Please stop saying simply "it doesn't work" and say exactly what doesn't work. Step one line of code. Check all your variables. Check the return value. Check the registry. See if the variables, return value and registry match what you expect. At some point they will not. Tell us exactly that point, what you get, and what you expect.

Comment: I added some watches: fileAndPath and get 0x46e0f0 <_ZSt16__convert_from_vRKPiPciPKcz+4645104> "C:\\Users\\Dannael\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\test.exe" and registryName like this 0x46e0e5 <_ZSt16__convert_from_vRKPiPciPKcz+4645093> "TestKey".. should be like this?

Comment: The problem is you are not listening to the suggestions. Your code was wrong - you are fixing it step by step. Functions return values - you should find the line with error status, you don't do it. Writing to HKLM requires privilege elevation - nobody knows if you are running the app with necessary permissions, or you just hit "access denied". Please re-read carefully what I wrote in the answer above, you just make everyone guessing.

Comment: I'm sorry for that.. I'm running the app first using normal privileges and then runing app as administrator...  Ok, i'll try re-read carefully..

Comment: I added this=> long j = RegSetValueEx(mykey, registryName, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)fileAndPath, size + 1);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != j)
   cout << "Error: Could not create registry key " << "\tERROR: " << j << endl;
  else
   cout << "Success: Key created" << endl; to my code. It returns code 6.

Comment: Update the code in question to exactly reflect all your changes. It is already workable, you most likely damaged it with something else.

Comment: Code updated.. running as admin and i get in console: Success: Key created \n Error: Could not create registry key j ERROR: 6 \n Error: Could not create registry key nResult ERROR: 6

Comment: Your printout is not good. Why do you print `j` three times? You should print `nResult` as well. You get `j` of 6 (invalid handle) because you already have an error in `nResult`, but what is it.

Comment: yes.. i've already noticed and corrected it. it's because of copy and paste.. Now the output is different, corrected too.

Comment: All right now, `5` is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` "Access is denied." and we're back to what I wrote before.

Comment: Problem solved... changed HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKEY_CURRENT_USER and it works.. key is created.. i also found some previously keys from working codes i have wrote before, i deleted the correct code because i could't find new keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid to copy string using something like:

```
void install (const char* fileAndPath, const char* registryName)
{
    const unsigned long size = strlen(fileAndPath);
    HKEY software;
    HKEY mykey;
    RegCreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\", &software);
    RegCreateKey(software, "Run", &mykey);
    RegSetValueEx(mykey, registryName, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)fileAndPath, size + 1);
    RegCloseKey(mykey);
    RegCloseKey(software);
}
```

Comment: Maybe use all *Ex* version as `RegCreateKeyEx`.